# Inheritance issue that i cannot understand

Tags: java, inheritance

I have this 2 classes:

```
public class A {
    protected int _x;

    public A() {
        _x = 1;
    }

    public A(int x) {
        _x = x;
    }

    public void f(int x) {
        _x += x;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "" + _x;
    }
}
```

```
public class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super(3);
    }

    public B(int x) {
        super.f(x);
        f(x);
    }

    public void f(int x) {
        _x -= x;
        super.f(x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A[] arr = new A[3];
        arr[0] = new B();
        arr[1] = new A();
        arr[2] = new B(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i].f(2);
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

The output is 3 3 6 and I am wonder why the third iteration is 6

Comment: Would you mind making the whole example somewhat reasonble? I do not mind reading code that itself is quite mind-numbling, however reading half-obfuscated variable/class names gets annoying quickly. Also add `@Override` tags.

Comment: Just go through the code in your mind... When you do not call a super constructor, the empty super constructor is called.

Comment: Write each step on paper. Remember that the first thing a constructor does if it doesn't explicitely invoke super() is to invoke the super constructor without argument.

Comment: @JB Nizet, except you call some other super constructor with arguments.

Comment: Yes, of course. Fixed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructor:

```
public B(int x)
{
    super.f(x);
    f(x);
}
```

is translated by the compiler to this:

```
public B(int x)
{
    super();
    super.f(x);
    f(x);
}
```

I guess now you would understand, why it's `6`.

Comment: after the first super _x = 1, and after that i have super.f(x) so it goes to f function inside A  class but because i have the function inside B class it implement f from B class and inside this f i have another time super.f(x) so it looks like recursion

Comment: @user3271698 `super.f(x)` won't call the overridden method.

Comment: Why not ? its B object

Comment: Because `super.f(x)` precisely means: call the superclass implementation of the `f()` method.